# Java service in docker container not connecting to host mysql

Tags: java, mysql, docker-compose

I have Java microservices running in docker container which is not able to connect to mysql hosted locally.

docker is running in network having ip address as 172.0.*.*.
If I execute Java service directly as java -jar, it is able to connect to mysql running in 10.0.*.*

docker-compose file

```
 version: '2.0'
services:
  config-server:
        image: test/config-server
        container_name: config-server
        environment:
          - GIT_USERNAME=${GIT_USERNAME}
          - GIT_PASSWORD=${GIT_PASSWORD}
        ports:
          - 8889:8889
        entrypoint: ["java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-Drun.arguments=GIT_USERNAME=${GIT_USERNAME}, GIT_PASSWORD=${GIT_PASSWORD} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
  discovery-server:
      image: test/discovery-server
      container_name: discovery-server
      links:
        - config-server
      depends_on:
        - config-server
      entrypoint: ["./wait-for-it.sh","config-server:8889","--timeout=60","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
      ports:
        - 8761:8761
  web-authentication:
      image: test/web-authentication
      container_name: web-authentication
      links:
        - config-server
        - discovery-server
      depends_on:
        - discovery-server
      entrypoint: ["./wait-for-it.sh","discovery-server:8761","--timeout=60","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
      ports:
        - 8444:8444
  gateway:
      image: test/gateway
      container_name: gateway
      links:
        - config-server
        - discovery-server
        - web-authentication
      depends_on:
        - discovery-server
      entrypoint: ["./wait-for-it.sh","discovery-server:8761","--timeout=60","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
      ports:
        - 81:8765
```

Comment: Post your compose file, and your Dockerfile...

Comment: @Dave - I have added docker-compose file, I am building docker image using maven plugin, so no DockerFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after configuring networks configuration in docker-compose.yml, the issue was mysql and Docker containers were running in different subnet.